# preserve edittext data when navigation back button pressed in android

Tags: java, android

In my application form there are several edittext where navigation back pressed my data in lost and focus didn't can i preserve that data after clicking navigation key back button how to over come this problem

Comment: The edittext text are appended using Custom List view

Comment: use SharedPreferences if you want to persist the data.

Comment: also you can try this https://gist.github.com/Cheesetouched/8c22fa27878eb8f5b3961391590a4b46

Comment: But to store in SharedPreferences i need current edittext view how can i get from custom list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer for this.In custom `edittext` which is used in custom list view,we have to save when every character is changed.

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
       }
       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {            
       }
       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String value =s.toString();
                mInterface.valueChanged((int)getTag(),value);
       }
});
```

This is value storing method

```
@Override
public void valueChanged(int position, String value) {
    EachField eachfld =(EachField) eachFields.get(position);
    obtDetails.put(eachfld.key,value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to posting on StackOverflow. Usually it's good practice to post what you've tried, instead of fix this for me questions, but since you're new here I'll give you the info you'll need.

When pressing the hardware back button onBackPressed is triggered, you'll need to override it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Then you'll need to set the activity result like this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
resultIntent.putExtra("edit_text_info", editText.getText().toString()); 
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
finish();
```

And start this activity for result:

```
startActivityForResult(Activity, ActivityRequestCode);
```

Then override the onresult of the activity calling the activity with the edittext

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == ActivityRequestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        editText = data.getStringExtra(ActivityRequestCode);
    }
}
```

After receiving the state from the activity with the editText keep it in a variable and return it once you navigate back to it with putStringExtra and... done.

An other solution is to create a fragment containing this edittext and keep the state in the activity, but my assumptions are that you're new to Android so this is probably easier (and of course better then defining a Singleton or something).

Comment: I used Custom list view to build activity here the problem is to hide keypad it will rotate back button to downwards when it is clicked the data is getting lost.I need to preserve that data I'm not changing any activity

Comment: A custom list view? Or custom list view adapter? You should really add code to your question and clearify yourself. Just saying "preserve" will result in me saying "create a variable"

Comment: yes this is actually the correct way to preserve any data on the activity. Just get the data what you need and save it in the bundle as @jobbert said. and retrieve it once you come the this activity.